# How to access Array elements in JSON object using handlebars

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, handlebars.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var data = {

    curreny :{
         name:'United States dollars',
         abbrev:'USD'

},
tours:[
  {name: 'Hood River' , price:'100'},
  {name: 'Sri lanka' , price:'150'},
  {name: 'Hood River' , price:'178'}
],
specialsUrl:'/january-specials'


}


router.get('/detour',function(req,res){
    res.render('tours',{object:data});
})
module.exports = router;
```

Above is the code I used to export JSON object into handlebars. I need to access tour details in the tour array in a handlebars file. How can I access those details to make a list of tour details inside h3 tag. Following is the sample tour.handlebars file. Thanks in advance.

```html
<h2> Hello this is the body section</h2>
<h3>currency : {{object.curreny.name}}</h3>

<h3>tours : {{object.tours.body}}</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over your `tours` array and then use it in handlebars like this:

```
{{#each object.tours}}
    <h3>name: {{name}} </h3>
    <h3>price: {{price}} </h3>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing data in the template then you can iterate like this:

```
{{#each tours}}
   <h3>name :{{name}}</h3>
{{/each}}
```